# How do I tell PG use the database.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

Here is a simple database connection, and query thats working for me;

```
postgre_conn = PG::Connection.open(:host => 'dbsvr', :user => 'csdashboard', :password => 'csdashboard', :dbname => 'csdashboard')

@filtered_snort_detail_query = postgre_conn.exec("SELECT * from event where timestamp >= (now() - '1 day'::INTERVAL);")
```

How can I tell pg to use the database.yml file for connection information?

```
#
#

Closed issue

#
#
```

I'm sorry to waist everyones time, I think I was doing this all wrong. Since this is a database function, I think it needs to be defined by a model first. Very sorry for that...

Comment: Post your `database.yml` file.

Comment: I guess you don't need that.If you specified adapter as `postgresql`,Rails will always uses the `dayabase.tml` to connect to the database given.

Comment: If have nothing in the code `postgre_conn = PG::Connection.open()` it errors out and asks if the database is local.

Comment: Try giving host as localhost.

Comment: But it is not local. I don't want to hard code hostname, username, and passwords, just use yml file.